# how to include remote images in org-mode export to LaTeX?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex

When I paste the URL of an image into an org-mode file and then export it to HTML, the remote image URL gets turned into an `img` tag and displayed in my HTML file without the need for me to save the image locally.

For instance, if I have a file `foo.org` consisting solely of the text `https://vetstreet-brightspot.s3.amazonaws.com/fa/19/73e1a8864e8a868b30d728f81431/most-popular-puppy-names-2016-thinkstockphotos-527135315.jpg`, it will export to an HTML file with a viewable image.

I'd like to do the same thing with PDFs. How can I include remote images when exporting to PDF via LaTeX?

Answer (score 1):

Try the latest org-mode. The Newsgroups, "gmane.emacs.orgmode" has an entry dated Sun, 19 Jan 2020, with news of a text/x-patch 0001-org.el-Add-inline-remote-image-display.patch.